# Connect PTVSD with VS Code through a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Flask application getting launch with Gunicorn inside a Kubernetes pod with the following command:

```
exec gunicorn --log-file - --access-logfile - --access-logformat "${LOGFORMAT}" \
     --no-sendfile -w 1 -t 600 --bind 0.0.0.0:${APIPORT-1380} ${EXTRABIND} ${ARGS} \
     -n apiwrapper "apiwrapper:create_app()"
```

I want to attach the PTVSD debugger to my app and link it to VS Code. Here is the lines I added to my function `create_app()`:

```
 if os.getenv("DEV"):
     import ptvsd     
     ptvsd.enable_attach(('0.0.0.0', 9797))
```

Our architecture is following this schema:

Ingress --> Service --> Pod

On my Kubernetes services I added:

```
    - port: 9797
      name: ptvsd-debugger
```

Which gives me:

```
backendapi                  ClusterIP   x.x.35.83     <none>        80/TCP,1380/TCP,9797/TCP   81m
public-site-standard-web    ClusterIP   x.x.214.19    <none>        80/TCP,8080/TCP,9797/TCP   83m
```

And I added the following route to my two ingresses:

```
- path: /debugger
  backend:
   serviceName: backendapi
   servicePort: 9797
```

```
NAME                        HOSTS                        ADDRESS          PORTS     AGE
public-site-standard-web    jocteau.aws.citizennet.com   192.168.50.101   80, 443   3h42m
backendapi                  jocteau.aws.citizennet.com   192.168.50.101   80        3h40m
```

Here is the `public-site` Ingress:

```
Name:             public-site-standard-web
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.50.101
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  dev-tls terminates myhostname.com
Rules:
  Host                        Path  Backends
  ----                        ----  --------
  myhostname.com  
                              /debugger   backendapi:9797 (x.x.x.25:9797)
                              /           public-site-standard-web:http (x.x.x.12:80)
```

and the `backendapi` Ingress:

```
Name:             backendapi
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.50.101
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host                        Path  Backends
  ----                        ----  --------
  myhostname.com  
                              /debugger         backendapi:9797 (x.x.x.25:9797)
                              /backend/api/v2   backendapi:http (x.x.x.25:80)
```

So now I created my debugger config inside VS Code:

```
{
   "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
   "type": "python",
   "request": "attach",
   "port": 80,
   "host": "myhostname.com/debugger",
   "pathMappings": [
      {
         "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/backend/py",
         "remoteRoot": "."
      }
   ]
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND myhostname.com/debugger
```

But when I try to access directly to the URL `https://myhostname.com/debugger`
I can see in my pod logs that my debugger is receiving the call:

```
E00139.153: Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ptvsd/ipcjson.py", line 269, in process_one_message
                msg = self.__message.pop(0)
            IndexError: pop from empty list
            
            During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
            
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ptvsd/ipcjson.py", line 258, in process_messages
                self.process_one_message()
......................
ptvsd.ipcjson.InvalidHeaderError: Malformed header, expected 'name: value'
```

What am I doing wrong with the VSCode configuration? Or is it impossible to do what I'm trying to achieve?
Thank you

Comment: You said that when you access the URL directly you have positive but you do it by hitting HTTPS. HTTPS uses port 443 and in your debugger config inside VS Code you configured it and everything else to use port 80. How is possible for you to get an answer on port 443?

Comment: Because the HTTP request are redirected to HTTPS thanks to the `public-site` ingress.
`public-site-standard-web    jocteau.aws.citizennet.com   x.x.x.101   80, 443   3h42m`.
I edited the question

Comment: So what if you configure your debugger config inside VS Code to use HTTPS?

Comment: I changed `port: 80` by `port: 443` and I get the exact same error

Comment: Changing the port is not telling it to use SSL communication. Do you know if it's supported?